# Resetting running total and count depending on the condition

Tags: oracle

I have a question in regards of the running total with reset in the oracle.

Running total for the sum and running count should accumulate for all of the operations made in last 6 days and reset if the conditions: `cummulative sum >= 3000 and count >= 2` are met.

That is I have the following table

| Sender_id | Date | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 23-01 | 1000 |
| 123456 | 24-01 | 2000 |
| 123456 | 25-01 | 4000 |
| 123456 | 26-01 | 2000 |
| 123456 | 27-01 | 3000 |

and the output should be given in the following format

| Sender_id | Date | SUM | Cumm_sum | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 23-01 | 1000 | 1000 | 1 |
| 123456 | 24-01 | 2000 | 3000 | 2 |
| 123456 | 25-01 | 4000 | 4000 | 1 |
| 123456 | 26-01 | 2000 | 6000 | 2 |
| 123456 | 27-01 | 3000 | 3000 | 1 |

How it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT sender_id,
       "Date",
       sum,
       cumm_sum,
       count
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY sender_id
  ORDER     BY "Date"
  MEASURES
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    SUM(SUM) AS cumm_sum
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (data+)
  DEFINE
    data AS COUNT(*) <= 2 OR SUM(SUM) < 3000
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Sender_id, "Date", SUM) AS
SELECT 123456, DATE '2021-01-23', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123456, DATE '2021-01-24', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123456, DATE '2021-01-25', 4000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123456, DATE '2021-01-26', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123456, DATE '2021-01-27', 3000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SENDER_ID | Date | SUM | CUMM_SUM | COUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 123456 | 23-JAN-21 | 1000 | 1000 | 1 |
> | 123456 | 24-JAN-21 | 2000 | 3000 | 2 |
> | 123456 | 25-JAN-21 | 4000 | 4000 | 1 |
> | 123456 | 26-JAN-21 | 2000 | 6000 | 2 |
> | 123456 | 27-JAN-21 | 3000 | 3000 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=55dfdb3289ffdcbde5c71251e5e50446)*